# Powershell for get-aduser for multiple users from a csv file with foreach

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get info of some users. I have a CSV file with their name test1.csv to get the required details I am using:

```
$name =  import-csv test1.csv | select -expand name 
foreach ($user in $name) {get-aduser -filter 'name -eq $user'}
```

But there is no output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change `'name -eq $user'` to `"name -eq '$user'"`

Comment: You can use `-LDAPFilter "(name=$user)"` too.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are correct that all you need to do is specify `-filter "name -eq '$user'"`.

However, often you can use this method to get all the users at once, which often works much faster:

```
$LDAPFilter = Import-Csv -Path test1.csv | ForEach-Object -Begin { '(|' } -Process { "(name=$($_.Name))" } -End { ')' }
$LDAPFilter = -join $LDAPFilter
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $LDAPFilter
```

Comment: Hehe that's a nice one